# Using ShellExecute to open file in browser

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to use ShellExecute to open a .txt file in the default browser.

I am currently using

```
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"http://E:/path/to/file.txt", 0, 0, 1);
```

This correctly creates a new window in the browser but tries to open

E/path/to/file.txt (without the ":")

and then can not find the associated file. The file location is definitely correct as manually adding the ":" back in the browser opens the file as desired.

Comment: Why do you want to display a `.txt` file in the default browser ? Create a html file

Comment: `http://` is ONLY for HTTP URLs. Use `file://` instead, and [mind the rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/).

Comment: Even if this _hack_ is working: have you tried what happens when your default browser is Chrome or Firefox ? Or a different version of the browser you are working with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

Use [AssocQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471(v=vs.85).aspx) or [IQueryAssocations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761400(v=vs.85).aspx) to figure out the default browser, then launch that browser with your text file on the command line.

## Option 2

Create a temporary `.html` file with a `<meta>` tag that [redirects](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html) to a `file://`  URL that loads the text file.  Then ShellExecute with your temporary `.html` file.  Since the temp file is of type `.html`, it should load the user's default browser.  The redirect will then cause the browser to load the text file.

The trick is figuring out when to clean up your temporary file.  ShellExecute doesn't make it easy to get a handle to the launched process (and, in reality, the process you launch may just launch another process), so you don't have an easy way to know when the browser is done with your temporary file.  You might just keep track of the temporary files you create and try to delete them when your application closes.

Answer (score -2):

ShellExecute will open a txt file inside the default text viewer, which isn't a browser I suppose. To open inside a browser, explicitely run the browser and give the file as argument. For example:

```
ShellExecute(
    0,
    L"open",
    L"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore",
    L"E:\\path\\to\\file.txt",
    0,
    1
);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to assume which browser to launch or where it is installed.

Comment: So you think that if I have to write a little program to do a very specific task on my very specific computer for example, I shouldn't make assumptions on the software installed and on their locations ?

Comment: You can do what you like on your own machine, of course.  But many developers use StackOverflow for advice on how to construct software used by others, so it's more valuable if the answers here deal in what's safe to do on other people's machines.